# Handsontable fixed column and row option shifting other rows and columns out of position

Tags: html, css, handsontable

I am currently working on a project with Handsontable and whenever I enable the fixed row and fixed column options the rest of the grid does not get aligned properly. This problem only occurs in visual studio as I have a static html document that it works fine on. I have looked for conflicting CSS formatting in visual studio but have not found anything.  Not to say that it's not there but just that I must have missed it if it is.

I have tried changing the number of rows and columns fixed and have tried changing the size of the cells but to no avail.  Upon further inspection I noticed that the grid cells are shifted up under the fixed rows.  Does anyone know how to go about fixing this problem or experienced this problem before and solved it?

(I have tried to add an image but am new to stack exchange and do not have any reputation yet. Hopefully I have described it well enough.)

**Edit**: I have just discovered that it is the fixedRowsTop option that is messing with the formatting if that narrows the search at all.

Comment: do you get the same bug on the browser?

Comment: When I run the static HTML file in the browser no.  Only when I use visual studio to launch the program into the browser.

Comment: not sure then, hard to debug such a thing. This was an issue a few versions back, but I'm not sure what visual studio has to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is after leaving it alone for about a week.  I still think it was some conflicting CSS styling, however I still did not find any specific conflictions.  Eventually my team decided that we wanted to do a different basis for the layout of the page.  So I added this line to my .cshtml document `layout = null` to erase any automatically generated basis for the page and the problem was fixed.

I'm assuming that the problem was some styling that the _Layout.cshtml document automatically had on it from the creation of the project and that I just didn't find the specific confliction.